# How to configure gcc in cygwin?

Tags: c++, gcc, configuration, cygwin

I installed cygwin with gcc 4.8.3 (to compile c++). All was well until I decided to build a 32-bit executable: a compilation error appeared when I compiled the code `#include <cstdlib>` (the error doesn't appear if I use `stdlib.h` instead of `cstdlib`).

After some digging, I found the following file:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bits/c++config.h

In that file, I have:

```
/* Define if __int128 is supported on this host. */
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_INT128 1
```

If I remove this code, the compilation error disappears.

Is this the right way to tune my gcc configuration? (I am almost sure it isn't)

If not, how should I do it?

---

For reference, here is the compilation error I was talking about:

```
$ echo '#include <cstdlib>' | g++ -c -m32 -x c++ -
In file included from <stdin>:1:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/c++/cstdlib:178:10: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘__int128’
   inline __int128
          ^
```

Comment: In an installation capable of handling several ABIs, there are several files c++config.h. If your version only has one, then it is not meant to handle -m32 and you need to install something else.

Comment: I just experienced similar with the `-m32` option, too. Gotta love it... You can't even report the bug because they don't appear to have a bug tracker: [Cygwin bug tracking is non-existent](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-06/msg00664.html). This bug will probably endure for a very long time....

Comment: Cygwin has a procedure for reporting problems and getting help.  If you think you're seeing a bug, it would be smart to ask about it there...  https://cygwin.com/problems.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the tarball from [one of GCC mirror sites](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html).  And follow the INSTALL instructions.  It's very straightforward, just did it *again* for 4.9.1.

For your problem, are you *on* a 32bit machine?  There's no need to **hack** the source code.  Have you run `./configure` properly?  Does your machine support 128bit `int`?  There *probably* be a parameter to `./configure` to state this yes or no.

Comment: The problem exists when using the  `g++`'s `-m32` option on `x86_64`.