# Why does Cygwin's GCC display the first line of every file?

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I'm not a regular Cygwin user. I installed Cygwin and Cygwin64 for testing proposed patches.

Here's the output of a typical make:

```
User@windows-7-x64 ~/cryptopp
$ make
g++ -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c shacal2.cpp
shacal2.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
 // shacal2.cpp - by Kevin Springle, 2003
 ^
g++ -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c seed.cpp
seed.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
 // seed.cpp - written and placed in the public domain by Wei Dai
 ^
g++ -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c shark.cpp
shark.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
 // shark.cpp - written and placed in the public domain by Wei Dai
 ^
...
```

Cygwin's make displays the first line of every file it compiles.

Why does Cygwin's make display the first line of every file? How can I stop the behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is due to the warning about the `-fPIC` command line option, just as it says.  Remove the `-fPIC` option from your makefile's `CXXFLAGS` (or wherever) and it will go away.

Comment: Thanks. *"... just as it says"* - actually, that appears to be a separate issue (at least to me). Specifying an non-existent option does not cause GCC to print the first line of a file. Cygwin is the only platform I have seen that warning. How do I disable the warning? Cygwin's GCC is not giving me one of those helpful `[-Wsome-warning]` messages to tell me how to turn it off.

Comment: @jww Have you tried other non-existent options with cygwin gcc to see that they don't also expose this behavior? This may be a cygwin gcc issue if it doesn't happen on other systems. It could also be a gcc version issue with only some versions needing to do this to have a target for the `^` marker they use.

Comment: @Etan - no, I know how GCC responds to non-existent flags and options. See, for example, this bug report I filed about ported GCC behavior: [GCC cannot compile an OpenMP program on OpenBSD](http://openbsd-archive.7691.n7.nabble.com/GCC-cannot-compile-an-OpenMP-program-td272519.html). Is the Cygwin project testing their stuff before they release it?

Comment: @jww The flag clearly exists (as opposed to something randomly mashed) and they chose to warn about it (I'm not sure why that seems pointless and actively anti-portable to me but *shrug*) and if the only way gcc does warnings requires a line of data to point at then I could understand using the first line of the file for it (since you need something and that's the obvious choice). You'd have to find another no-op-and-warning option to see if cygwin gcc has consistent behavior there and on another system (using a linker flag might work too).

Comment: Umm... all this conversation about testing other options, etc. seems beside the point to me.  Did you remove the `-fPIC` option?  Did the warning go away?  Did the display of the first line of the file go away?

Comment: @Etan - if they had a bug reporter, I'd be happy to report it. But they don't, so this will probably stay broken for quite some time (a lot like [How to configure gcc in cygwin?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25748613), which has been broke for a couple of years).

Comment: @MadScientist - yes, removing `-fPIC` caused it to go away. But it introduced a new problem: a crash. I'm experiencing it on Fedora 22/i686 without PIC, MinGW 32-bit without PIC, and Cygwin 32-bit without PIC. So it looks like Ive got a bad interaction with GCC 4.8 and above with 32-bit and without PIC. I guess its time to pick my poison. (And I can't wait for all the user bug reports this generates....)